# Insert int type variable from EditText into SQL Database in Android

Tags: android, sql, string, android-edittext, integer

I got an EditText and I want to insert an **int type variable** into my database. If I insert a number, everything's ok. But if I left the EditText empty, the app crashes. This is the code that handles this and I think it's an **Integer.toString()** problem or something like this.

```
int target;

if (targetNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        target = Integer.parseInt("");
    } else {
        target = Integer.parseInt(targetNumber.getText().toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't parse "" to int. You can store 0 for example

```
int target;

if (targetNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    target = 0;
} else {
    target = Integer.parseInt(targetNumber.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, didn't I add a 0 in the corresponding row inside the Database? My goal was to leave it empty

Comment: Then you just shouldn't write data to your db in case of targetNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()

Comment: And how can I set the "don't write data" condition?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help you with it. I haven't seen your full code

Comment: But can't I pass the analog of empty space string for an int?

Comment: No. It can't be empty it's primitive type. You can store 0 or -1 for example and then check if it's < 1 or < 0. But I think the best way don't call method which write it to db at all.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
 target = Integer.parseInt("");
```

with

```
target = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to make use of a ternary operator:

```
int target = targetNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(targetNumber.getText().toString())
```